# abstract class error in EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to ask how to solve problem in my CacheBean. It uses my custom EJBTestObject to store time. This class is associated with maven projects via dependencies in pom.xml.

I'm still getting errors:

```
wipb/jee/clientdemo/ejb/CacheBean.java:[17,8] wipb.jee.clientdemo.ejb.CacheBean is not abstract and does not override abstract method add(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object) in wipb.jee.clientdemo.ejb.CacheBeanRemote
wipb/jee/clientdemo/ejb/CacheBean.java:[39,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
2 errors
```

EJBTestObject:

```
public class EJBTestObject {

private String content;
private long lastAccess;

public EJBTestObject(String content, long lastAccess) {
    this.content = content;
    this.lastAccess = lastAccess;
}
..getters and setters

}
```

CacheBean:

```
@Singleton
public class CacheBean implements CacheBeanRemote {
private Map<String, EJBTestObject> cache = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public EJBTestObject get(String key) {
    System.out.println("Cache.get called");
    return cache.get(key);
}

@Override
public boolean contains(String key) {
    System.out.println("Cache.contains called");
    return cache.containsKey(key);
}

@Override
public EJBTestObject remove(String key) {
    System.out.println("Cache.remove called");
    return cache.remove(key);
}

@Override
public void add(String key, EJBTestObject value) {
    System.out.println("Cache.add called");
    cache.put(key, value);
}
}
```

CacheBeanRemote:

```
    @Remote
public interface CacheBeanRemote {

void add(String key, EJBTestObject value);

EJBTestObject get(String key);

boolean contains(String key);

EJBTestObject remove(String key);

}
```

I noticed when I do not use EJBTestClass in add method everything works fine.

Comment: change/add `public void add(String key, EJBTestObject...` to `public void add(String key, Object...`!

Comment: Works fine, I am really grateful. Can you explain exactly what's going on here?

Comment: since you `implement` a (foreign) interface, you "contract" to provide its methods ..this is ensured (by the compiler) via the "method signatures" (=name, return type, type & index (not the name) of parameters).